# What is "A man only does something that sits easily with his conscience." translated into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

The infamous and long-discredited legal defence: "I was only obeying orders.", has become almost the traditional excuse for cowardice & brutality.

Of the legal (There is a higher moral duty to disobey orders.) and non-legal counter-arguments, one of the most apposite was: "A man only does something that sits easily with his conscience."

How to express these opposing views, in Latin?

> "mihi iussus parendi erant." = "By me orders had to be obeyed."

A CONTRAST:

The English (I was only obeying orders.) is almost a plaintive, pathetic plea for sympathy e.g. "I only spilt some coffee."; the Latin, with the gerundive-of-obligation, reinforces the myth, being propagated, that the executioners were somehow compelled to commit their crimes.

The second is trickier. I tried a result (so-that) construction but the second clause is supposed to describe the accomplishment; not the effect the accomplishment had on the subject's mind, isn't it?

> "vir solum facit aliquem ut non suam conscientiam perturbet" =

> "A man only does something so that it does not trouble his conscience.";

does not work.

A relative clause:

> "aliquid non fit viro quod suam conscientiam perturbet." =

> "Something is not done by a man that troubles (may trouble) his conscience."

This, using the passive of "facio", doesn't sound correct either. Some help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the verb *exonerare* is used in a passage of Q. Curtius Rufus (*Historiae Alexandri Magni* 6.8.12) to describe unburdening one's conscience, it follows that *onerare* is one verb that could be used of the opposite. I tend to think that sentiments like this work somewhat better in the negative in Latin.

> *nihil quod oneret conscientiam faciunt homines.*
>
> Humans do no sort of thing that would burden their conscience.